# How to run a python script on a server 24/7?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a python script which I have to run on AWS 24/7. How can I do that? Should I just run it as I'd do locally:

```
python3 main.py
```

Or should I be:

```
python3 main.py &
```

?

Is there any difference where I put it: in the home directory? Or in subdirectory? Does it matter at all?

Comment: Actually I'd have a different script that is run by cron every minute that checks to see if your script is not running or hung and kills/restarts it if it needs it before exiting.

Comment: how can the 2nd script check if the 1st is running?

Comment: In the case of my script if the size of the output file is the same as it was 1 minute ago then somethings wrong, the output file doesn't really get gigantic but if it's the same as it was 60 seconds ago then somethings broke

Comment: @Tyson but in my case it doesn't.

Comment: I don't have any idea what your script does do, or what version of 'ps' you have available.  You can already resort to having the .py script write the time to a file and the bash/cron script can check for incrementing  time.  Here's some other ideas https://opensourcehacker.com/2012/11/26/pgrep-and-pkill-your-linux-scripting-process-management-friends/

Answer (score 4):

What operating system are you running this on?  You should strongly consider using the native init system.  If you are lucky, you'll be using something with systemd, and then a service file is very simple to write.

```
[Unit]
Description=My awesome program

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/awesome.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 3):

There are more options:

- you can do as you suggested by using `python3 main.py &` and then closing the ssh pipe (using without `&` will make the script exit when you close the ssh connection)
- you can set a cron job for the script
- once I did a simple bash script that will listen for new information on a remote git server and run the updated script every time a new change was made

  - this could be a good idea if you're planning to update the script and make different deployment changes;
  - I wold first create a script that runs as a service at boot time, checking that everything is ok and up to date, then it will start my desired script periodically, checking for updates;
  - is not necessary to use git, another example might be using `rsync`;

---

EDIT:

Monitoring the script:

- monitoring the resources that the vm uses from AWS;
- sending an email with the output of the process currently running on the system or some kind of a log;
- creating a mini web interface showing what services are running;
- using a monitoring tool like Sensu, Nagios, Datadog, etc.

Comment: how can I monitor the script to ensure it's running?

Comment: Install it as a service and start / monitor it with Monit : https://mmonit.com/monit/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `screen` ([man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen))

To start your program:

- Log in with ssh,
- Launch screen: `$ screen`
- Start your program:`$ python3 main.py`
- Detach from screen using key combination C-A(Ctrl+A) + D,
  (what's in your screen session will keep running)
- Log out from ssh

To check again your program execution:

- Log in with ssh (with the same user as before)
- Re-attach to an existing screen session using `$ screen -r`

Comment: or tmux, for just the one program they are equally useful but tmux is better interactively.